# having issues with downloading tweets using homebrew and python

Tags: python, bash, macos, homebrew

here us the code i came up with:

```
import tweepy
import openpyxl
from tweepy import OAuthHandler, API, Cursor

consumer_key = "bRrYCLX32EoYRgSGK9eh5rM0w"
consumer_secret = "7VvseOrVdGnFUVU8euXQS9xjlJu5pp9XwrlmxIElCWzWvx4jmD"
access_token = "1652157781699448832-zM2H2nm6OdoJMTG8Ja6VAuPEyPhNMD"
access_token_secret = "SO5QH5IFJELSG8jqqP3yMKZXfhmQI3Sp5uDy4CDyXkMTX"

# Authenticate API credentials
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = API(auth)

keywords = ["covid", "coronavirus", "cure", "remedy", "homemade"]
language = "en"
num_tweets = 100

# Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet to write the data
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Write headers to the worksheet
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Username"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Tweet Text"

# Write tweets to the worksheet
row_number = 2
tweets = Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                q=keywords,
                lang=language,
                tweet_mode='extended').items(num_tweets)
for tweet in tweets:
    worksheet.cell(row=row_number, column=1).value = tweet.user.screen_name
    worksheet.cell(row=row_number, column=2).value = tweet.full_text
    row_number += 1

# Save the workbook
workbook.save("tweets.xlsx")
```

here is the error:

```
/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/bin/python /Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.api import API
  File "/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Users/josehuertas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with LibreSSL 2.8.3. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and here is my homebrew installed packages:

```
(base) josehuertas@Joses-Macbook-Pro ~ % brew list --versions
ca-certificates 2023-01-10
openssl@1.1 1.1.1t
openssl@3 3.1.0
```

here are the listed installed packages  in miniconda:

```
type he(base) josehuertas@Joses-Macbook-Pro ~ % conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/josehuertas/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                    openblas    anaconda
boltons                   23.0.0          py310hca03da5_0  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h1a28f6b_1002  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h620ffc9_4  
ca-certificates           2022.4.26            hca03da5_0    anaconda
certifi                   2022.6.15       py310hca03da5_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h80987f9_3  
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda                     23.3.1          py310hca03da5_0  
conda-content-trust       0.1.3           py310hca03da5_0  
conda-package-handling    2.0.2           py310hca03da5_0  
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0           py310hca03da5_0  
cryptography              40.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4             py310hca03da5_0  
joblib                    1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonpatch                 1.32               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jsonpointer               2.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
libcxx                    12.0.0               hf6beb65_1    anaconda
libffi                    3.4.2                hca03da5_6  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_2_0_he6877d6_26    anaconda
libgfortran5              11.2.0              he6877d6_26    anaconda
libopenblas               0.3.20               hea475bc_0    anaconda
llvm-openmp               12.0.0               haf9daa7_1    anaconda
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0  
numpy                     1.22.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.22.3          py310h5e3e9f0_0    anaconda
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1t               h1a28f6b_0  
packaging                 23.0            py310hca03da5_0  
pandas                    2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.0.1          py310hca03da5_0  
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310hca03da5_1  
pycosat                   0.6.4           py310h1a28f6b_0  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyopenssl                 23.0.0          py310hca03da5_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310hca03da5_0  
python                    3.10.10              hc0d8a6c_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python.app                3               py310h1a28f6b_0  
pytz                      2023.3                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
requests                  2.30.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py310h1a28f6b_0  
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6           py310h1a28f6b_1  
scikit-learn              1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3           py310h3c8eff0_0    anaconda
setuptools                65.6.3          py310hca03da5_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
sklearn                   0.0.post4                pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.1               h80987f9_0  
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               hb8d0fd4_0  
toolz                     0.12.0          py310hca03da5_0  
tqdm                      4.65.0          py310h33ce5c2_0  
tweepy                    4.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2023.3                   pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.38.4          py310hca03da5_0  
xz                        5.2.10               h80987f9_1  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5a0b063_0  
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310h80987f9_0  
(base) josehuertas@Joses-Macbook-Pro ~ % re
```

i have tried redownloading open SSL and reinstallingt multiple tims... i have tried reinstalling homebrew... i have asked chat chatGPT to help but it tells me to run it in an environment where the newer versions of open SSL can be accessed..... i run the code it tells me but it appears to do nothing...

Comment: Are those your actual API keys? If so, you need to reset them now...